# BigQuery window function to match previous record

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, window-functions

I'm looking for a window function to retrieve a value in a previous record in `BigQuery` by comparing a value in the current record until it finds the most recent match. Here is a sample table:

[image]

```
with a as (
  select 1 as hitNumber, 'xx' as sessionID, 'aaa' as pageName, null as convPageName
  union all
  select 2 as hitNumber, 'xx' as sessionID, 'ccc' as pageName, 'bbb' as convPageName
  union all
  select 3 as hitNumber, 'xx' as sessionID, 'ccc' as pageName, null as convPageName
  union all
  select 4 as hitNumber, 'xx' as sessionID, 'ddd' as pageName, 'qqq' as convPageName
  union all
  select 5 as hitNumber, 'xx' as sessionID, 'eee' as pageName, 'ccc' as convPageName
  
)
select *, ??? as prevConvPageName from a
```

Based on this example, looking at `hitNumber = 5`, I want to know what the `convPageName` is for the most recent record where the `convPageName` matches the `pageName` and the `convPageName` on the matching record is not null. In this case, the result would be `bbb` because the `convPageName` for `hitNumber = 5` matches the `pageName` for `hitNumber = 2`.

Comment: `WITH a AS (
  SELECT 1 AS hitNumber, 'xx' AS sessionID, 'aaa' AS pageName, NULL AS convPageName
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS hitNumber, 'xx' AS sessionID, 'ccc' AS pageName, 'bbb' AS convPageName
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS hitNumber, 'xx' AS sessionID, 'ccc' AS pageName, NULL AS convPageName
)
, b AS (
  SELECT
    *,
    -- Use LAG to get the previous convPageName
    LAG(convPageName) OVER (PARTITION BY sessionID ORDER BY hitNumber) AS prevConvPageName
  FROM a
)
SELECT a.*, b.prevConvPageName FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.hitNumber = b.hitNumber`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be solved by using `FIRST_VALUE` in combination with joining table `a` with it self.

Please note that I added an extra row to table `a` in order to prove that the latest record from table `a` based on hitNumber, is used.

```
WITH
  a AS (
  SELECT
    1 AS hitNumber,
    'xx' AS sessionID,
    'aaa' AS pageName,
    NULL AS convPageName
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 2,'xx','ccc','fff'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 3,'xx','ccc','bbb'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 4,'xx','ccc', null
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 5,'xx','ddd', 'qqq'
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 6,'xx','eee', 'ccc'
)

select distinct
  outer_a.*,
  FIRST_VALUE(inner_a.convPageName)
    OVER (PARTITION BY inner_a.pageName ORDER BY inner_a.hitNumber desc
  ) as convPageNameMapped
from
  a as outer_a
  left join a as inner_a on 
    outer_a.convPageName = inner_a.pageName
    and inner_a.convPageName is not null
```

**Result**

[image]

If only matched records should be included in the result, please replace `left join` with `join`.

**Relevant documentation**

[Navigation functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions)